# Images and Script not working on deployment environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, thinktecture-ident-server

Everything works fine on my development environment, but when from production environment it doesn't load images, and also giving error of "$" is undefined on $.document jquery function.

The site is built using ASP.NET MVC.. there is "Images" folder on root, and "Scripts" folder on root as well.

I have checked the permissions on these folders and IIS users are given read access over there.

Not sure, but its worth mentioning that I am using thinktecture as an identity server.

Comment: Do you have taken the jquery-1.4.1.js or higher version on that page

Comment: yes, I am using version 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check your jQuery reference on that page using View Source (Ctrl + U), if it's there?

OR

may be you had reference wrong path for jQuery on that page .

OR

may be you have using multiple jQuery files on page and your files is Conflict with others.

you can debug your problem using Firebug in Firefox.

Hope this will help you.... :)